# MYSQL: used variable on IN condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

[EDIT]
The query below is not the actual query which I am having issues with performance. It is only a simplified query. As I only would like to know if it is possible to store multiple results into a variable and used that variable into the IN condition.

I had this query below inside a procedure which I would like to change for optimization.

```
SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (SELECT facility_id FROM facility);
```

What I would like to do was to store the subquery into a variable and used that variable on the main query.

```
SET @facilities = (SELECT facility_id FROM facility);

SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (@facilities);
```

But I got an error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. How should I do it? Any help is appreciated.

I have found some link that suggest that way http://www.mysqlperformancetuning.com/how-to-speed-up-mysql-by-optimization?nocache=1#comment-961. But I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Did you identify this as a performance bottleneck? Unless your SP is doing a lot of stuff with that result set this looks like a lot of hard work for little gain. You can probably get a bigger boost by changing the sub query to a join (mysql traditionally handles joins better than subqueries but benchmark!!)

Comment: @e4c5 This is not the actual query. I just simplified it. Basically the query takes at least 20 seconds and sometimes reaches 60 seconds to execute. It involves views also which make it complicated.

Comment: Well in that case I think you will need to edit your question and post a more indicative query. Clearly judging by the answer you got, I am not the only one who wondered if this was a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @facilities = (SELECT facility_id FROM facility);
```

This query will be valid only if your table `facility` has only one record else it would result in the error which you are getting. Presently your query is returning more than one record which you cannot store in a variable and hence resulting in the error.

Comment: Is there a way to store multiple results into a variable? Like an array type.

Comment: @Pelang:- Why you want to do that? `SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (SELECT facility_id FROM facility);` is good enough. Whats the performance issue you are getting with this query?

Comment: I read somewhere that having subquery in WHERE could affect the performance. The query i presented is a simple query. But the working query I have. I have several more IN condition that uses subquery which I would like to eliminate.

Comment: @Pelang:- If the two tables are linked then you can JOIN the tables. That would help.

Comment: In my case, the main query's FROM is a view that is made from a join of a view and a table. And on the WHERE condition I got 6 more IN condition that uses subquery. So if I have to use INNER JOIN will it not still be slow?

Comment: @Pelang:- There is nothing like array in MYSQL, you can try to get the values in a temporary table but that would be the same thing(*instead it would create an overhead*). You can check the performance using the JOINS. There should be some difference in performance using JOINS. Also I don't think you can optimize the query in your `IN` clause anymore.